# Pagination using numbers instead of cursor

Tags: php, symfony, graphql, api-platform.com

I'm using Symfony 5 with the latest version of api-platform. Running PHP 7.3.

I'm using the graphql api and trying to achieve a number based pagination.
In the [current documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#pagination) only cursor based pagination is explained. OR is there a way to paginate like [1][2][3][4][5] based on the cursor? AFAIK not.

I've also read the `ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\Pagination` class and looked into the `getOffset` and `getLimit` functions. So I tried in my query to pass numeric values but it resulted in "Cursor 0 is invalid".

The query:

```js
`before: "0", after: "10"`
query SearchOrders($first: Int!) {
  orders(first: $first, before: "1", after: "10") {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `master` version of API Platform (or to wait for the new release).
The page-based pagination has been added in it.

See https://api-platform.com/docs/master/core/graphql/#using-the-page-based-pagination for the documentation.

Comment: Ah thank you! Will be patient until then. Any chance you could help [with this question too?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60709951/2535171)