# How to implement a search in multiple fields in API Platform and Sylius?

Tags: search, filter, symfony4, api-platform.com, sylius

I'm implementing a product search in Sylius `1.8.5` (based on API Platform `2.5.7` and Symfony `4.4.16`).

The basic variant for the search in the `product.translations.name` (see the code below) is working. But now I want to be able to search in multiple fields, e.g. in `product.translations.name`, `product.translations.description`, and `product.translations.short_description`. The problem is, that adding of further criteria will just make the filtering stricter, because the logic behind it, implemented in the `ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter`, only knows the `AND` connector and uses the `andWhere(...)` internally.

Sure, as workaround I can simply override the API Platform's `SearchFilter` by a custom one and change the logic how I want. But maybe there is a more elegant / built-in solution for this case? I have the feeling, it should be, since the scenario I want to implement is a very common one and probably needed in nearly every (shop) application with a (product) search functionality.

**What is a proper way to implement a (product) search in multiple properties / fields in API Platform / Sylius?**

---

**`services.yaml`**

```
imports:
    - { resource: "filters.yaml" }
```

**`filters.yaml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
...
<resources ...>
    <resource class="%sylius.model.product.class%" shortName="Product">
        <collectionOperations>
            <collectionOperation name="admin_get">
                ...
            </collectionOperation>
            <collectionOperation name="shop_get">
                <attribute name="method">GET</attribute>
                <attribute name="path">/shop/products</attribute>
                <attribute name="filters">
                    <attribute>sylius.api.product_order_filter</attribute>
                    <attribute>sylius.api.product_taxon_code_filter</attribute>
                    <attribute>sylius.api.translation_order_name_and_locale_filter</attribute>
                    <attribute>shop.product_search_filter</attribute> <-- added
                </attribute>
            </collectionOperation>
            <collectionOperation name="admin_post">
                ...
            </collectionOperation>
        </collectionOperations>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

**`filters.yaml`**

```
services:
    # Filter Services
    shop.product_search_filter:
        autowire: false
        autoconfigure: false
        public: false
        parent: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.search_filter'
        arguments: [ { translations.name: 'partial', translations.locale: 'exact' } ]
        tags: [ name: 'api_platform.filter' ]
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709951/filter-query-on-multiple-fields-in-single-query