# API Platform search filtering on relations columns

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have a project in Symfony, Im using Api Platform.

For example, I have two entities:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    privat $firstName;
    
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $lastName;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Book::class, mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $books;
}

class Book
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $title;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Book::class, inversedBy="books")
     */
    private $user;
}
```

And I want to enable Search Filter on many columns like (user.firstName, user.lastName and book.title)

So when I write for example "Shakespeare", this should find this world in all of mentioned aboved columns.

I found this solution: [filter query on multiple fields in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709951/filter-query-on-multiple-fields-in-single-query)

But it works perfectly for columns in one table, but I want to filter for many columns from tables includes relations

Answer (score 0):

so by default ApiPlatform works with relation filters, for that you need to define the filter like this:

```
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={
 *   "user.firstName": "ipartial"
 * })
```

So you just need to specify the relation field, in this case "user" and the field.

Comment: Okey, but it works for single column. But I want to type as a parametr: ?search= Shakespeare and It would find that word in columns: (user.firstName OR user.lastName OR book.title)
Your solution works only for column "firstName"

Comment: Unfortunately ApiPlatform does not support that by default, so you need to make a Custom filter, an example you can find in another stack overflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709951/filter-query-on-multiple-fields-in-single-query